# Secure Access-Control-Allow-Origin for App

Tags: php, android, cross-domain

I have an Android and iOS app made by PhoneGap and I communicate with PHP using
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

It's not secure, however. How can I do something like:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: JUST MY APP");
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` security is implemented by web browser. When you're out of the browser world as in your case, this header won't help you. You need to implement a authentication/authorization mechanism in your API